# How do I give each topping a new line

Tags: python, string, list, function, arguments

```
def make_pizza(*toppings):
    # To print a list of toppings that have been requested
    print("\nMaking a pizza with the following toppings:")
    for topping in toppings:
        print("- " + topping)

print("We have pepperoni, mushrooms, green peppers, and extra cheese.")
print("What toppings do you want on your pizza?")
my_toppings = str(input())
make_pizza((my_toppings))
```

We have pepperoni, mushrooms, green peppers, and extra cheese.

What toppings do you want on your pizza?

mushroom, green pepper

Making a pizza with the following toppings:

- mushroom, green pepper

How do i get it to say:

Making a pizza with the following toppings:

- mushroom
- green pepper

Comment: worded that wrong i'm not trying to get the code on each line im trying to get the response not be one line

Comment: It seems you need to split on a comma, as your `toppings` is just one string and not a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I get it, I think you’re trying to achieve something like this:

```
def make_pizza(toppings):
    # To print a list of toppings that have been requested
    print("\nMaking a pizza with the following toppings:")
    for topping in toppings:
        print("- " + topping)

print("We have pepperoni, mushrooms, green peppers, and extra cheese.")
print("What toppings do you want on your pizza?")
my_toppings = input().split(", ")
make_pizza(my_toppings)
```

Example:

```
We have pepperoni, mushrooms, green peppers, and extra cheese.
What toppings do you want on your pizza?
> pepperoni, mushrooms, green peppers
-pepperoni
-mushroom
-green peppers
```

Comment: Making a pizza with the following toppings:
- mushrooms,
- green
- peppers   green and peppers should be on the same line

Comment: @AdamSafi How about now? If there’s any more fine modifications, you should be able to fix it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need this in one-line as this is much less readable, but if you want this for learning purpose you can use the following:

```
def make_pizza(*toppings):
    # To print a list of toppings that have been requested
    print("\nMaking a pizza with the following toppings:\n{}".format("\n".join(["- {}".format(topping) for topping in toppings])))
```

Comment: @ Dekel I think you missed the point of the quesiton sorry for any confusion on my part i am new to stack overflow! @abccd gave the answer I was looking for. Thank you for the help. If you could upvote the question I would appreciate it!